# Textarea Count Lines, Count hyphenated Lines using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to figure out the issue with using regular expressions to ignore lines starting with double hyphens and count the single lines as separate and double hyphenated lines counted as separately and display outside the text area.

I have tried and got success with counting the each line but ignoring hyphens and counting I have no idea on how can I do that using regular expressions.

On another side, I want to append the code inside of a span Item buts it's removing the text of item element.

**Here is my code and sample Image.**
[image: Sample Image of Final Output]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var items = $('#items');
    var groups = $('#groups');
    
    $('#ingredients_list').keydown(function(e) {
        newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
        items.text(newLines);
    });
});
```

```css
.ingredients__section {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ingredients__section textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.ingredients__section h2 {
  color:#0433a7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ingredients__header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.ingredients__title { display: table-cell; }
.ingredients__countinfo { display: table-cell; text-align:right; }

.item-count,
.group-count { padding: 5px 15px; background-color:#e4ebef; margin-left: 5px; font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ingredients__section">
<div class="ingredients__header">
<div class="ingredients__title"><h2>INGREDIENTS</h2></div>
<div class="ingredients__countinfo">
  <span class="group-count" id="groups">Groups:</span>
  <span class="item-count" id="items">Items:</span>
</div>
</div>
<form>
    <textarea id="ingredients_list" rows="15"></textarea><br />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Its good but when I develop it into PHP the string translations would be difficult from javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize counters

```
var groupsCount = 0;
var itemsCount = 0;
```

Get array of entered text

`var arrayOfItems = $(this).val().split("\n");`

Run for all elements in array and check first two symbols. If it is `--` then `groupsCount++` else `itemsCount++`

```
for (var i=0; i<arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
  if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '-' && arrayOfItems[i][1] === '-') {
    groupsCount += 1;
    itemsCount -= 1;
    groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
  } else {
    itemsCount += 1;
    items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var items = $('#items');
    var groups = $('#groups');
    
    $('#ingredients_list').keypress(function(e) {
        var groupsCount = 0;
        var itemsCount = 0;
        var arrayOfItems = $(this).val().split("\n");
        for (var i=0; i<arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
          if (arrayOfItems[i] != '') {
            if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '-' && arrayOfItems[i][1] === '-') {
              groupsCount += 1;
              groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
            } else {
              itemsCount += 1;
              items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
            }
          } else {
            groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
            items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
          }
        }
    });
    $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
        var groupsCount = 0;
        var itemsCount = 0;
        var arrayOfItems = $('#ingredients_list').val().split("\n");
        for (var i=0; i<arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
          if (arrayOfItems[i] != '') {
            if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '-' && arrayOfItems[i][1] === '-') {
              groupsCount += 1;
              groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
            } else {
              itemsCount += 1;
              items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
            }
          } else {
              groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
              items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
          }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ingredients__section {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ingredients__section textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.ingredients__section h2 {
  color:#0433a7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ingredients__header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.ingredients__title { display: table-cell; }
.ingredients__countinfo { display: table-cell; text-align:right; }

.item-count,
.group-count { padding: 5px 15px; background-color:#e4ebef; margin-left: 5px; font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ingredients__section">
<div class="ingredients__header">
<div class="ingredients__title"><h2>INGREDIENTS</h2></div>
<div class="ingredients__countinfo">
  <span class="group-count" id="groups">Groups:</span>
  <span class="item-count" id="items">Items:</span>
</div>
</div>
<form>
    <textarea id="ingredients_list" rows="15"></textarea><br />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and appreciated the code you have added. but looks like a minor glitch in it. When I add a section with `--` it is taking a first entry into the item instead of a group. If I remove everything and click outside it should be zero for both. How can we do that in it?

Comment: @Maqk I update my post and add `mousedown` event on page. also I add check for empty string. check it!

Comment: @Zhenya-Telegein  - Instead of `if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '-' && arrayOfItems[i][1] === '-') {` can we use a regular expressions instead using conditional codes for finding strings with double hypens?

Comment: @Maqk you can use `arrayOfItems[i].substring(0, 2) === '--'` :) `substring(0, 2)` will take first 2 symbols :) feel free to ask questions! sorry that I made dumb check in code :P

Answer (score 0):

Its good, But I have seen that if you type a word with double hyphens `--` or without the same `--`, it is adding `+1` to both `groupItems` and `listItems` which are not what you are looking for.
It means if you start group name with `--` it should add `+1` to `groups` instead of `items`, so here is the small change in your code that might help you to fix.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var items = $('#items');
var groups = $('#groups');

$('#ingredients_list').keypress(function(e) {
    var groupsCount = 0;
    var itemsCount = 0;
    var arrayOfItems = $(this).val().split("\n");
    console.log(arrayOfItems);
    for (var i=0; i<arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
      if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '-' && arrayOfItems[i][1] === '-') {
        groupsCount += 1;
        groups.text("Groups: " + groupsCount);
      } if (arrayOfItems[i][0] === '.'){ // I have given '.' here in single quote, you can add regex what you are looking for like numbers, letters, or expressions that start with. 
        itemsCount += 1;
        items.text("Items: " + itemsCount);
      }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but your code works only if it starts with a group. if it starts with the items then it won't count.